# How can i scan my fingerPrint using phone sensor in Android?

Tags: android, sensors

i am new to sensors.
I have to create an application in which bio-metric system is used. Through this phone scan finger print with sensors(Without usage of camera) in kitkat or lollipop.
I google for it a lot but didn't find any idea or solution of it.

Please if anybody have some knowledge about this concept, please share it.
Provide me any useful/logical link or better if any kind of source you have.

Thanks in advance, any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure there is such API call for scanning finger print till lollipop.

Comment: There are some API, as this is a part of samsung S5, it dont think it is impossible

Comment: For eg, see the link:-     https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog/

Comment: Samsung is using their own API call. we should never compare with Factory OS with Custom OS. Lot more android phones having fingure print sensor, but they uses their own CODE not from ANDROID API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**finger print** security api https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html ,its the new api introduced in 6.0 . Biometric Security – In an effort to enhance  security, the much needed system-wide biometric fingerprint will be  provided by Android Marshmallow. The user can unlock devices with  fingerprints and purchase apps on Google Play

Comment: I just want to scan finger print to match my data? how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

> Through this phone scan finger print with sensors(Without usage of camera) in kitkat or lollipop

That is not possible, other than for Android devices that have a fingerprint sensor (e.g., Samsung S5) and offer an API for it (which Samsung might, as part of their Mobile SDK, though I have not looked).

> see the link:- github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog

That is for Android 6.0.

Comment: Thanks, but can you tell me the Proper procedure how to bio-metric system works?